# Free starter theme to make mobile websites?

Tags: theme-development, mobile

Is there any free starter theme to make mobile websites using WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are a few - did you search for them? Here are the top results from Google:

- [WPTouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/)
- [Carrington Mobile](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/carrington-mobile)
- [WordPress Mobile Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/)

Comment: WPTouch is the quickest way to make this.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend utilizing [960.gs](http://960.gs) to create custom grids if you have a current existing theme.

960gs allows you to easily convert a theme into various layouts.